# Will my saved games work with a new copy of GTA 5?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I have a PS3 (somewhat of a noob). I lost my DVD of GTA 5 and need to buy a new one. Will my saved games work with a new copy of GTA 5?

Answer (score 2):

Provided you mean that you'll be buying another copy on the PS3, then yes, your existing save files/dlc will still work. :)

**edit** Of course, I should note that you'll have to ensure that the new copy is from the same region as the original, as that may play a part also.